# How to establish VBA macro to copy and paste a range instead of singular cells to a MS Word doc?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro below that essentially takes an excel cell and pastes into a MS word table. Right now, I have 4 excel cells per "observation" that have to be copied and pasted into an MS word table that has 5 columns and two rows. When pasting the cells (A, E, F, I), they need to go into column 1, 2, 3, and 5 respectively for the table.

Does anyone know if there is a way to condense the below code to a simple range? Instead of telling the macro to copy this, paste that, copy this, paste that.. etc., I would like to tell it to copy this range, paste it, then move to the next entire observation table.

```
    Dim tb13 As Excel.Range
    Set tb13 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Observation Listing").Range("A10")
    tb13.Copy

    myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=True, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=True
    
'Obs Summary
    Dim tb14 As Excel.Range
    Set tb14 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Observation Listing").Range("E11")
    tb14.Copy

    myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=2).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=True, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=True
    
'Pot. Bus. Impact
    Dim tb15 As Excel.Range
    Set tb15 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Observation Listing").Range("F11")
    tb15.Copy

    myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=3).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=True, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=True
    
'Action Plan
    Dim tb16 As Excel.Range
    Set tb16 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Observation Listing").Range("I11")
    tb16.Copy

    myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(Row:=2, Column:=5).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=True, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=True
```

Comment: When you write VBA code to do something you are just automating what can be done manually in the UI. So before you attempt to write code figure out how to do what you want manually. Then you can automate that. If you can’t perform the operation as you want to in the UI, you won’t do it in code either.

Comment: Do you just want the value/text of the Excel cells copied into your Word table, or do you want to copy/paste the Excel cell's formatting as well?

Comment: Formatting as well. So basically right now the macro goes cell by cell and pushes it to word in the designated table. I am trying to simplify the macro and instead tell it to take 3 cells at once and paste them in the word doc in the correct cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: for expample by 'Obs Summary

```
myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(2, 2).Range.text = _ 
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Observation Listing").Range("E11").value
```

You can use this cycle to loop through the range and write all cell values into the table:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim col As Long, r As Long
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ObservationListing").Range("A11:C11")
col = 1 'start with this column
r = 2 ' row
For Each v In rng.Cells
    myDoc.Tables(4).Cell(r, col).Range.Text = v.Value
    col = col + 1
Next v
```

Comment: Is that .Cell statement pointing the VBA pasted range (E11) to the row 2, col 2 in Word?

I am looking for something that can take, for example, A11:C11 and paste that into a word doc table. Right now when i try that, it literally takes A11:C11 and pastes that entire 3 cell range into one single "cell" in my MS Word table. I need it to paste A11 in row 2 col1, B11 in row2 col2, and C11 in row2 col3. Does that make sense?

Comment: this is great. I was able to use this and it worked. Now I have some work to do with formatting and could use your help..

So right now the actual project has a different range. I need to pull cells A11, E11, and F11 into MS Doc table row +1 etc. Is there any way to specify this? I tried changing the range to ("A11", "E11", "F11") but that did not work.

After I get that done, I am wondering if there would be a way to make sure the formatting is brought from Excel to Word. I added "WordFormatting:=True,_" but that gave me a Compile error: Expected: expression.

Comment: Hi, I also have limited knowledge. I would go with making formatting in Word and not copying the format from excel. Everything is depends, what kind of formatting it is and at what point it is decided how to format. E.g. if the formatting is fixed, than definitely in Word, if the formatting is changing according to the excel values than as far as I know there are two ways: using copying (not like I suggested to write the values), or getting the format requirements in Excel and making the formatting in Word accordingly.